# Where to store the DB connection for a classmethod/staticmethod

Tags: python

I have something similar to the following:

```
class InferredProvider(object):

    def __init__(self):
        from ingest.parse_utils import DB
        db = DB()
        self.conn = db.conn
        self.cursor = db.cursor

    @classmethod
    def update_all(cls):
        x = InferredProvider()
        conn = x.conn
        cursor = x.cursor
        for item in ... [etc]
```

Initializing the DB seems fine for an instance...but doing it for a classmethod to `update_all` items seems a bit odd. What would be the suggested way to do this here?

Comment: To the (limited) extent that it’s appropriate for `InferredProvider().do_stuff()` (with no arguments!) to know what database to use, it seems reasonable that `InferredProvider.do_stuff2()` should know as well; there is no semantic difference of data flow, and the syntax difference is trivial.

Comment: @DavisHerring would there be a better way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Generally, I think that components that *select* actions (in this case, the database to use) should be separate from those that *implement* them.  Then there’s no temptation to have functions with no arguments and with significant side effects (which is what strikes me as “a bit odd” here).